# Multi-Variable Gradient Descent using Numpy - Error in no. of coefficients

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

For the past few days, I have been trying to code this application of Gradient Descent for my final-year project in Mechanical Engineering. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tIGqZ2Lb0sN4GEpgYEZLFvtmhigXnot0 The HTML file is attached above. Just download the file, and if you see the results. There are only 3 values in theta, whereas x has 3 independent variables. So it should have 4 values in theta.

The code is as follows. For the result, it is theta [-0.03312393  0.94409351  0.99853041]

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        # avg cost per example (the 2 in 2*m doesn't really matter here.
        # But to be consistent with the gradient, I include it)
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
        # update
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
    return theta

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\WELCOME\Desktop\FinalYearPaper\ConferencePaper\NewTrain.csv', 'rU', delimiter=",",header=None)


x = df.loc[:,'0':'2']
y = df[3]
print (x)

m, n = np.shape(x)
numIterations= 200
alpha = 0.000001
theta = np.ones(n)
theta = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)
print(theta)
```

Comment: `theta` has as many values as you define it to have. If `n == np.shape(x)[1] == 3` and `theta.shape == n`, `theta` will have 3 values. I don't understand your question.

Comment: from concept perspective, coefficients number is same as your input feature number. from code, you defend the number of theta equal to the feature size, theta = np.ones(n)

Comment: I am guessing you want to estimate the intercept to the y-axis as well (`y = t0 + t1*x1 + t2*x2 + t3*x3`). You need to add on column of one to  `x`.

Comment: Yes, @Eolmar Could you pls elaborate "you need to add on a column of one to x". How to add it ?

Comment: I can't run your code, so I guess something like that: `x = df.loc[:,'0':'2']; x['3'] = 1.0` before running the gradient descent

Comment: yeah, it's running. But the coefficient values are far away from what excel gives. @Eolmar I defined y = df[3]

Comment: I can't help you if you do not provide enough info do reproduce and understand your problem (x,y and expected output)

Comment: I have attached below screenshot 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18DgkyKyrAJtIp0qgREuhpElCC-PEobI9/view?usp=sharing 
Mentioned x1,x2,x3 and y. I need the regression coefficients. @Eolmar

Comment: I am not retyping value from the screenshot. I don't see why adding a column of constant to x to have the intercept should not work. Did you try it ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12axINSw2fCO6rog56lxFjFj5evvKj9aS/view?usp=sharing
Here are the code and result after adding a column one to x. @Eolmar
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-UaU34w3c5-VunYrVz9fD7vRb0c-XDqk/view?usp=sharing Also the csv file I entered

Comment: @xdurch0 As Eolmar pointed, I have added a column of 1 to x. Then I am getting wrong coefficients as the answer as compared to excel. I believe there's something wrong with the math.

Comment: @galaxyan By adding a column of 1 to x. I am getting 4 coefficients for 3 independent variables. Which is correct, but the value is wrong. I guess something wrong with the math.

Comment: @Eolmar Any help from your end buddy?