# Gradient Descent numpy Python - discrepancy between excel and calculated data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Writing this algorithm for my final year project. Used gradient descent to find the best fit line. I tried solving it with excel too using Multi-regression. The values are different.
The csv file is attached here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-UaU34w3c5-VunYrVz9fD7vRb0c-XDqk/view?usp=sharing. The first 3 columns are independent variables (x1,x2,x3) and the last is dependent (y). 
Its a different question, If you could explain why the answer is different from excel values?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
    return theta

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\WELCOME\Desktop\FinalYearPaper\ConferencePaper\NewTrain.csv', 'rU', delimiter=",",header=None)

df.columns = ['x0','Speed','Feed','DOC','Roughness']

print(df)

y = np.array(df['Roughness'])
#x = np.array(d) 
x = np.array(df.drop(['Roughness'],1))
#x[:,2:3] = 1.0
print (x)
print(y)

m, n = np.shape(x)
print(m,n)
numIterations= 50000
alpha = 0.000001
theta = np.ones(n)
theta = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)
print(theta)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-Variable Gradient Descent using Numpy - Error in no. of coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674212/multi-variable-gradient-descent-using-numpy-error-in-no-of-coefficients)

Comment: @eolmar It's different, I am unable to understand why the answer of the above code is different from one in Excel